# Access EC2 machine with local IP instead of elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I have an Amazon EC2 instance that I have been using for production and for some weird reason I did not use an Elastic IP.

Now that I want to use an Elastic IP, it seems AWS doesn't allow connection on the old IP. In my use case I need the instance to be accessible through both IPs. Is this really possible?

Comment: Your question says "local IP", but your question seems to be asking about Public IP addresses. Could you please clarify what IP addresses you mean by "both IPs"?

Comment: By local I meant ip of instance before allocation of elastic ip to instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot use the old public IP once you associate an elastic IP. Remember you have only one network interface, you cannot have 2 public (routable) IPs associated with it.

From [Elastic IP Address Basics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html)

> If you associate an Elastic IP address with the eth0 network interface
>   of your instance, its current public IP address (if it had one) is
>   released to the EC2-VPC public IP address pool. If you disassociate
>   the Elastic IP address, the eth0 network interface is automatically
>   assigned a new public IP address within a few minutes. This doesn't
>   apply if you've attached a second network interface to your instance.